# tty resolution breaks down after suspend & resume on Linux

Tags: linux, grub, resolution

I am running

```
$ uname -sr
Linux 4.0.5-gentoo
```

with an Nvidia GeForce 750 Ti card and

```
$ eix nvidia-drivers
[I] x11-drivers/nvidia-drivers
     ...
     Installed versions:  355.11-r2^msd(01:51:54 04/12/15)(X acpi gtk2 multilib tools uvm -gtk3 -pax_kernel KERNEL="linux -FreeBSD")

$ eix grub
[I] sys-boot/grub
     ...
     Installed versions:  2.02_beta2-r7(2)^t(16:24:02 18/07/15)(fonts multislot nls sdl themes truetype -debug -device-mapper -doc -efiemu -libzfs -mount -static -test GRUB_PLATFORMS="-coreboot -efi-32 -efi-64 -emu -ieee1275 -loongson -multiboot -pc -qemu -qemu-mips -uboot -xen")
```

The only uncommented entry in my `/etc/default/grub` is `GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Gentoo"`.

When I boot up the system, Grub starts up in text mode (which looks like `640x480` resolution), and so does the kernel (I can read the boot log). After `X` is started, the resolution switches to the native resolution for my monitor (`1920x1080`). After I log in, I can switch to tty1-6 (`Ctrl+Alt+F1-6`) with no issues.

When I suspend the system and subsequently resume it, *sometimes* before displaying the login screen the monitor flashes with **green and purple vertical stripes** several times. After that, the login screen is drawn normally. However, switching to tty1-6 ceases to work. Here is what the monitor looks like if I try:

[image: tty artifacts]

This does not necessarily happen the first time I suspend during a session. The same black&white vertical stripes are drawn instead of the shutdown log. After a reboot, the ttys are back to normal.

I have replaced my monitor and my video card recently. This issue did not arise with the previous configuration.

This is probably unrelated, but I have tried to experiment with various settings in `/etc/default/grub` to set the boot resolution to a higher value. While `GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080` did work, setting `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep` caused a black screen during the entire boot procedure, up until the login screen (which was drawn normally). Eventually I decided to leave everything at default values.

---

1. How do I diagnose what is wrong with my video system?
2. How do I fix it?

---

**UPD:** it *seems* that emerging `sys-apps/v86d` solved the issue. I'll post a more complete clarification when I'm more confident about that.